# How to preserve the datatype 'list' of a data frame while reading from csv or writing to csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, dtype

I want to preserve the datatype of a column of a data frame which is a list while writing it to csv file. when I read it, I have to have the values in lis format.

I have tried

```py
pd.read_csv('namesss.csv',dtype = {'letters' = list})
```

but it says

```py
 dtype <class 'list'> not understood
```

this is an example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jack','johnny','stokes'],
                  'letters':[['j','k'],['j','y'],['s','s']]})
print(type(df['letters'][0]))
df
```

```
<class 'list'>
name    letters
0   jack    [j, k]
1   johnny  [j, y]
2   stokes  [s, s]
```

```py
df.to_csv('namesss.csv')
print(type(pd.read_csv('namesss.csv')['letters'][0]))
```

```
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ast module` to make strings into lists :

```
import ast
df2 = pd.read_csv('namesss.csv')
df2['letters'] =[ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df2['letters'] ]

In [1] : print(type(df2['letters'][0]))
Out[1] : <class 'list'>
```